# Highlight multiple adjacant textblocks in a XAML Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) App

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am modifying an application that reads in a document, and then generates a TextBlock for each word in the document and then outputs it to the screen.

Each TextBlock has the IsTextSelectionEnabled property set to true, and this works for highlighting the word, or part of the word in an individual TextBlock.

My question is whether it is possible to allow the user to select "across" TextBlocks, so they can then highlight multiple words (TextBlock controls) at the same time.

At the moment, other code in the App relies on there being individual TextBlock controls for each word -

This is something I can change if required, but I wondered if there is a built in, or simple way to allow the user to select multiple adjacent TextBlocks? Otherwise I will look to implement something myself and post my solution here at a later date.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, it would work if all the words were added as separate `Runs` in a `TextBlock` or `RichTextBlock`